# Best way to pad image based on the edge pixels (row-wise)

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I want to pad an object based on edge pixel to replace the zeros.

I am not sure if `padarray` is applicable to this, I am showing a sample code below to replicate my need. I am able to do it but I think this is not an efficient way as I am scanning each row at a time to find and pad the zeros.

```
%% Example code to recreate my need
image = imread('moon.tif');
[~, ncols] = size(image);
image(image <50) = 0;
image = fliplr(image(:,1:round(ncols/2)));
% figure, imshow(image,[])
BW = bwareafilt(logical(image),1);
% create bounding box
boxProps=regionprops(BW,'BoundingBox'); 
cords_BoundingBox = boxProps(1).BoundingBox;
% Extract sub_Image
sub_Image = imcrop(image, cords_BoundingBox);
% figure, imshow(sub_Image,[])
%% This is the part I want to use better or existing function for padding
duplicate_sub_Image = sub_Image;
[nrows, ~] = size(duplicate_sub_Image);
for nrow = 1:nrows
    % current_row_inverted = fliplr(sub_Image(nrow,:));
    [~,col,pad_value] = find(duplicate_sub_Image(nrow,:),1,'last');
    duplicate_sub_Image(nrow,col+1:end) = pad_value;
end
figure, 
subplot(131),imshow(image,[]), title('original image');
subplot(132),imshow(sub_Image,[]), title('bounding box image');
subplot(133),imshow(duplicate_sub_Image,[]), title('row padded image');
```

[image]
Any suggestions to improve this code or use of existing functions to address this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Which result are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The right most image with padding

Comment: So you want to replace all the rows of black pixels, just on the right side of the image (?) with **what**?

Comment: I want to replace the zero pixels in each row with the last non-zero element in that row. My images are either to left or right, I would flip the image for this purpose so each look like pad to right side

Comment: yes. I am going to use flip in that case. The filename tag mentions whether its left and right to identify

Comment: Can you please include **everything** necessary to run your code - including the import statements so we are using the same modules and also supply the images **separately** so we can load `moon.tif` individually without having to hope we crop the montage the same as you. Thanks.

Comment: This code is ready to run on matlab with moon.tif image from the matlab images in toolbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way without using loops:

```
[~,imin] = min(sub_Image, [], 2);
col = max(1, imin-1);
ind = sub2ind(size(sub_Image), (1:numel(col)).', col);

duplicate_sub_Image = sub_Image(ind) .* ~sub_Image + sub_Image;
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly. I have to cast here: `duplicate_sub_Image = sub_Image(ind) .* cast(~sub_Image,class(sub_Image)) + sub_Image;`